# SQL Server : query using synonym in remote server

Tags: sql-server, indexing, linked-server, synonym

We just migrated our database environment from server 1 to server 2.
We are in SQL Server 2014 (old and new servers).

In the previous environment, we had a `DATABASE_1` with a `Table_a` (in which there is an clustered index) and a `DATABASE_2` that contains a `synonym_a` referencing the `DATABASE_1.dbo.table_a`. The query using this synonym (`SELECT with JOIN`) was running fine (select top 10000 in 1s).

Now, we have one server with `DATABASE_1` with the `Table_a`, and another server (linked server) with `DATABASE_2` with `synonym_a`.
The same query is running very slow. I can see the execution plan is different between the 2 environment. The index in `table_a` is not used in the new environment.

We tried to add `WITH INDEX` but it is not possible to specify an index hint for a remote data source. We need the synonym (because the same code is deployed automatically in different site and can't have the name of server/database in the code of our queries, stored procedure). And we can't replace the view by a stored procedure.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: Remote queries are known to be slow, especially when you are performing a `JOIN`. The *entire* remote table needs to be pulled from the remote instance, and then written to `tempdb` as work table, and then that will be joined against. Sometimes, however, the instance will do that operation once **per row**. Often you are better off inserting the entire remote table into a local temporary table first, and then joining to that instead of the remote table. If you can, limit the number of rows as much as you can from the remote instance first as well.

Comment: Why did you split the db on to a different server in the first place? Whatever problem you solved, you now have another one. Linked servers are a bad idea.

Comment: But why the index of the Table_a is not used? There is a way of forcing its use?

Comment: Splitting the servers was to avoid the single point of failure as we have many big databases/applications of major activities of our company in the db server. For now we will try to solve out issues with this environment.

Comment: You can try `remote join` with linked servers - this may help, if most of 'joining' needs to be done at remote server.

Answer (score 0):

when you use link server execute plan couldn't see the index of another server that you have link.So when use query by join server A send the request to another server by itself plan and ignore the index by the way
try the chance by use this query

```
select * from (
    select * from Table_a order by (column that index in server 2)
              )a inner join (
    select * from server2.db.owner.table_b order by column)b
    on a.id=b.fkid
```